# iOS: behavior of "settings changed" notifications when app is terminated

Tags: ios, notifications

Sorry, these might be stupid questions, but the Apple doc doesn't really go into any great detail.

- suppose a listener is set up, but then the app is closed and "wiped up", what happens if the user changes the settings?
- if I don't remove the listener in the termination event, then there will still be a reference open, does ARC ensure the listener is still accessible?
- is the notification queued until the application starts up again, or does it get lost, or never created?

Comment: UILocalNotifications or NSNotifications?

Comment: [NSNotificationCenter, code like this: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appSettingsDidChange:)
                                             name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];`

Comment: OK and when you are talking about settings, are you referring to some settings panel within your app or are you have you added controls to Settings.app?

Comment: Controls to Settings app.

Comment: The docs suggest synchronizing the defaults when you come back to fore to get the new values. However, your app could be coming back after being quit or a crash. In those situations your listener is now gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try synchronizing NSUserDefaults when your comes to the foreground. See *Synchronizing and Detecting Preference Changes* here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html

If it's a fresh launch, your previously registered listener is gone. You could register the listener before synchronizing, but if there was no caching (like the docs mention), then you would also not receive the notification. So you may just want to treat the settings as if the had been changed whenever you come to the foreground.